# Firebase Hosting config requires public field when using Github Actions but works if deploying locally?

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting a NextJS web app on Firebase Hosting.  I'd like to get the Github Actions Integration to work for distributing my web app.

In the documentation, the `public` field is required but I specify a `source`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply

When I run `firebase deploy --only hosting` on my local machine (with no `public`), everything works as intended and my web app is deployed.

My issue is using Github Actions.  When I approve my Pull Request on Github, the Action triggers but has an error on the `FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0` step:

```
Must supply a \"public\" directory or at least one rewrite or redirect in each \"hosting\" config.
```

### .firebaserc

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}
```

### .github/workflows/deploy-to-firebase-hosting.yml

This is autogenerated by the `firebase init hosting` command.

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR merge
"on":
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CHECKMATE_PROD }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: myproject
```

I added `"public": "public"` to the `.firebaserc` which is successful in deploying but the page looks like this:

[image]

From what I can see my issues are:

- Include `public` field but Firebase Hosting doesn't see anything in the file.  Maybe I'm not specifying the correct `public` directory?  Not sure if this is different if NextJS build runs.

  - ChatGPT suggested I use `out` as the public directory but this resulted in an error `Error: Directory 'out' for Hosting does not exist.`
- Include `source` but Firebase Hosting requires a `public` (yet I can get away from `public` if I deploy locally)

Comment: Suddenly I started having the same issue (it was working until 1 hour ago). I suspect it's a bug on the experimental `webframeworks` feature, but can't prove it yet. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Fappaz I have not

Comment: I moved to cloudrun via terraform/docker and it was a lot more transparent. I would recommend the same. I can share some config if it helps. I wanted to use this framework as I thought it would split the deployment into multiple functions but I'm not sure it does so there doesn't seem to be much upside.

Comment: That might be useful for secure end to end solutions.  For my personal use case, I just run `firebase deploy --only hosting` from my command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that upgrading `firebase-tools` made this issue go away.

`npm install firebase-tools`

When I upgrade and rerun the v2 becomes v3:

```yaml
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
```

There are a myriad of other issues with permissions I need to resolve but at least this issue is no longer the case.